# × Migration failed: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin: Socket timeout

Tags: angular, npm, ng-upgrade, ng

I am trying to upgrade from angular 15 to angular 16.
i get this error after running "ng update @angular/core@16 @angular/cli@16"

I tried clearing cache, maxing the timeout I even deleted Nodejs and reinstalled it and am still getting the same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.